# Is there a way to take user input and turn it into a variable for JS?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I currently have a webpage, and I want the user to be able to input their name and age. Once they've done that, they hit submit, and the first input is set to var name, and the second input box is set to var age. Is this possible?

Here's what I've tried

```
<form>
    <input type="text" Name:"firstname"><br>
    <input type="text" Age:"age"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Done">
</form>
```

Im not sure how to go about setting the input to values however.

Comment: So read the input value and set it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly - your HTML markup is incorrect. I would sincerely suggest you read up on this.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp 
and
https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
or
any other site of your choice.

Secondly - once you correct your markup - you can do as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname">
<input type="text" id="age">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Set The Variables">

<script>
//Get the dom element you want to listen to and attach a click event
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", setVars); 


function setVars(){
//Set the variables
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
alert ("Vars Set :" + firstname);
}
</script>
```